# T-SQL error if use dollar and bracket symbols together

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I'm getting the following error message with execution T-SQL script with this construction "$(", in sqlcmd utility:

```
C:\Users\Admin>sqlcmd -S DESKTOP-5AA9JIA\SQLEXPRESS -q "select '$(' " -R
Sqlcmd: Error: Syntax error at line 1 near command '''.
1>
```

if run this script via SSMS then everything works smoothly.

Getting the same error, when using INSERT INTO statement or any other statement.

Any suggestion on how to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `-x` when launch `sqlcmd` to ignore `scripting variables`.

> -x
>
> Causes sqlcmd to ignore scripting variables. This is useful when a
>   script contains many INSERT statements that may contain strings that
>   have the same format as regular variables, such as $(variable_name).

[sqlcmd Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017)

When sqlcmd parser sees `$(`it expects scripting variable that is not provided so it throws the error.

Here is my test:

[image]